# Python: is RuntimeError acceptable for general use?

Tags: python, exception

Is it acceptable to use the RuntimeError exception for general application use?

```
raise RuntimeError('config file is missing host address')
```

I've got some code with a couple of one-off situations like this and would prefer to avoid creating one-off exception classes for each of them.  All the situations are fatal, and my goal is to get a clear message to the console.  Basically I'm looking for something similar to the deprecated

```
raise 'config file is missing host address'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is... OK.  Ideally, you *would* have separate exceptions for each reasonably distinct situation (e.g. one exception for all "the config file is malformed" errors, reuse `FileNotFoundError` in 3.x for "the config file doesn't exist", etc.).  But this is one of the more innocuous forms of technical debt.

The downside is that if you ever do introduce those separate exceptions, they may need to subclass from `RuntimeError` for reasons of backwards compatibility.  That's kind of ugly, but mostly harmless.

Comment: On the contrary, I would say that many exception classes would anyways reasonably derive from `RuntimeError`: A `RuntimeError` simply means some error that was only detectable at runtime, rather than when the software was designed: An error out of the hands of the developer. This is in contrast to say a `TypeError`, where under careful analysis of the program flow, you should have been able to see that you are actually using a type inappropriately.

Comment: @burnpanck: `OSError` and its friends do not derive from `RuntimeError`.  Nor does `ValueError`, `KeyError`, etc., yet those are all reasonably possible runtime errors.  RuntimeError is largely a "miscellaneous" bin, and I don't like extending it.

Comment: True, I guess it is anyways not always clear if something was reasonable detectable before runtime or not. In practice it seems to matter very seldom (at least in my use-cases), as either you expect something very specific, or you have `except Exception:`, or you anyways just look at the traceback.

Comment: @burnpanck `except Exception`? Surely just `except`.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: [Don't use bare except:](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except).

Comment: @Kevin: ... unless you are going to re-`raise` it afterwards, for code that needs to run whenever a protected block doesn't run to it's end. However, these cases are often better solved with a `with`-statement/context manager or a `finally:` clause.

Comment: @burnpanck Is there an error for when it was in the programmer's hands but they dropped it?  Like "The program should never reach this branch, but you found a case that we didn't think of that does"

Comment: @endolith: That's what the `assert` statement is for.

Comment: @Kevin So... `assert False` in places that should never be reached?  That doesn't seem like a user-friendly error message.

Comment: @endolith: It's not meant to be user-friendly, it's meant to be programmer-friendly. Your code should behave correctly when asserts are turned off altogether (e.g. with `python -O`).

Comment: I'm pretty alright with this before my code is in production when the bug has to do with malformed data for example:
`
except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
`